# Custom message to endpoint from WSO2 APIM

Tags: wso2-api-manager

Is it possible to send custom message or unique message to the endpoints for each request via WSO2 API Manager/APIs?

Comment: What do you mean ? Do you have any example ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The API Manager is in its most basic sense an API Proxy/API Gateway, so whatever you send to it it will pass through to the back-end.